# How can I display a firebase field into a listview in flutter

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I've been doing my best to code in flutter these days but i'm still a total newbie.

I've been trying to display a querysnapshot onto a list view and display it on my screen.

For that, I have this API call that helps me get all of the orders that are present in my Firebase field :

```
    Future fetchOrders() async {
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestoreInstance
        .collection('requests')
        .where('status',isEqualTo: 'open')
        .get();
    return qn.docs;
  }
```

And I also have my widget build that looks like this :

```
       @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchOrders(),
          // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
          builder: (_,snapshot){
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
          return Center(
            child: Text("Loading ...")
          );
        } else{
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index){
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["start"]),

            );
              });
        }
      }),
    );
  }
```

My data based looks like this:
[image]

Finally, I've been getting this error and I'm not sure that I got it right :

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '[]'
Receiver: Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.
Tried calling: []("start")
Found: []() => Map<String, dynamic>
```

I'm so sorry if this was already answered.
Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `data` written one too many times in your `ListTile`.

Change this

```
 Text(snapshot.data[index].data["start"])
```

to this

```
Text(snapshot.data[index]["start"]
```